# Count specific column values by year in another date column in Excel

Tags: excel, countif

I have an excel table with two columns and several hundred rows. One column lists a single-digit code that represents an event, the other the date of that event.  I'm attempting to count the number of times a particular event (say "1") occurred in a particular year (say 2017).

I normally use "COUNTIFS" for two or more criteria, but I'm stumped by the date format. I can't seem to get it to work in the formula.  In this case, I'm using the yyyy-mm-dd format. How can I perform this operation?

```
A small example of the table is as follows:
 ------------------------
     A          B
 --+--------------------+
1  Event      Date     
2    1     2016-09-12 
3    1     2019-10-11 
4    3     2017-03-24
5    2     2016-05-25
6    3     2017-08-02
7    1     2018-10-11
```

Comment: What is the formula you have tried?  What were the actual and expected results?

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,1,B:B,">="&DATE(2017,1,1),B:B,"<="&DATE(2017,12,31))
```

**EDIT:**

if you have *text-that-looks-like-dates*, you can use `SUMPRODUCT` and `YEAR`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A7=1)*(YEAR(B2:B7)=2017))
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. The result I get is "12/30/99".  I must add that I'm working with LibreCalc instead of MS Excel.  I'm hoping to get just an integer as a result.  Would LibreCalc use a different way to code the formula?

Comment: Then change the format of the cell to General or Number. Though the result `36524` doesn't match with your setup of only several hundred rows.

Comment: Now I get "0".  I'm pretty sure I have several hundred that meet the criteria.

Comment: Are your dates actual dates, or *text-that-look-like-dates*? Probably the latter.

Comment: Good catch.  The dates are really text-that-look-like dates. Let me try reformatting the date cells to DATE.

Comment: Changing the format won't change them to an actual date... Dates are just formatted numbers.

Comment: Try using `DATEVALUE` to convert them to dates in a new column.

Comment: That would work. I tried it on a couple of rows.  I just need to convert the entire "date" column into a new column with DATEVALUE.  I'll try it.

Comment: It worked, but it involves too many steps.  I'm looking for a formula that will address the date without converting it to the date serial or number.

Comment: See the revision.

Comment: I'll give it a try at my first opportunity and let you know.  Thanks.